# Getting NoMethodError: undefined method error in ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error while running the command `rake routes` using ROR.

> Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `resources' for nil:NilClass
C:/Sites/bookshelf/config/routes.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Sites/bookshelf/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Sites/bookshelf/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:in `execute_if_updated'
C:/Sites/bookshelf/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
       root 'books#index'
       resources :books  do |book|
           book.resources :comments, :only => :create
       end
end
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
       root 'books#index'
       resources :books  do
           resources :comments, :only => :create
       end
end
```